# Hiding a result of a function in R

Tags: r

I created a function that has four output arguments, for example:

```
myfuction<-function(...){     
    #Inside the function I created four results A, B, C, and D.    
    A = ...    
    B = ...    
    C = ...    
    D = ...     
    z<-list(MacKinnon=A,regression=B,proof=C, res=D)    
    return(z)
}
```

The result D corresponds to a vector of numbers that respresents the residuals of a regression.

My question is How can I hide this result without removing it? That is, I want that when I run the function, the results A, B, and C appear, but not the result D.

And if I want to access the result D, I have to do something like this:

```
X <-myfuction (...)
X$res
```

to be able to observe the residual.

Comment: You can assign your returned list a class and write a custom print method for that class, but that's a lot of work just to hide a value from the screen.

Comment: as MrFlick notes, this requires an object oriented design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would just use an S3 class. Basically, just tag the object `z` with a particular class

```
myfunction <- function(){     
  #Inside the function I created four results A, B, C, and D.    
  A = 10;B = 20;C = 30; D = 40     
  z = list(MacKinnon=A, regression=B, proof=C, res=D)    
  class(z) = "my_fun" # Tagging here
  return(z)
}
```

Create an S3 print function for `my_fun`

```
print.my_fun = function(x, ...) print(x[1:3])
```

Then

```
R> x = myfunction()
R> x
$MacKinnon
[1] 10

$regression
[1] 20

$proof
[1] 30
```

But

```
R> x$res
[1] 40
```

gives you want you want.

---

A couple of comments/pointers.

- Typically when you assign the class, you would use something like

  ```
  class(z) = c("my_fun", class(z))
  ```

  however, since we just created `z` in the line above, this isn't needed.
- Currently the `print` method strips away any additional classes (in the example, there is only one class, so it's not a problem). If we wanted to maintain multiple class, we would use

  ```
  print.my_fun = function(x, ...) {
    x = structure(x[1:3], class = class(x)) 
    NextMethod("print")
  }
  ```

  The first line of the function subsets `x`, but maintains all other classes. The second line, then passes `x` to the next `print.class_name` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found it very useful

Comment: In general, it may be safer to use `class(z) = c("my_fun", class(z))` to ensure inheritance of any other pre-existing methods that you don't want to explicitly define.

Comment: @dww Thanks - I've updated the answer. It's not really needed here, but it's good to mention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`invisible`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/invisible.html).

For example, this would print nothing to the console but allow you to assign it's output:

```
myfunction<-function(){
    #Inside the function I created four results A, B, C, and D.
    A = 1; B = 2; C = 3; D = 4
    z<-list(MacKinnon=A,regression=B,proof=C, res=D)
    return(invisible(z))
}

myfunction()       # nothing prints
x <- myfunction()
x                  # now it does!
# $MacKinnon
# [1] 1

# $regression
# [1] 2

# $proof
# [1] 3

# $res
# [1] 4
```

If you want specific parts printed to the console, you can use `print` or `cat` for those.

```
myfunction<-function(){
    #Inside the function I created four results A, B, C, and D.
    A = 1;    B = 2;    C = 3;    D = 4
    z<-list(MacKinnon=A,regression=B,proof=C, res=D)
    print(A)
    return(invisible(z))
}

myfunction()
# [1] 1
```

This is useful if you don't want the output to be printed when the function runs without being assigned. If you don't want it to print after it's been assigned to a variable, then you should create a `print` method like @csgillespie suggested.